# Is there a way to view all custom marker icons in the Google maps javascript API?

Tags: javascript, api, maps, markers

**The Issue:**

I've viewed the tutorial on the Google Maps API documentation on how to change the icon of a marker. Here's a screenshot of that:
[Google Maps tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuEOc.png)

In this tutorial though, they don't actually elaborate on how they got the link to that icon. And I would like to know if there's anyway to view all the available icons and their corresponding links.

**What I've tried**

1. I tried going directly to the link: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/", but that returns a 404 error.
2. After doing some research, I found this: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/geicons.htm ...This should work, but the icons are a bit outdated and don't really fit with what I'm going for.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)